# Matlab LDPC Decoder Problem with LLRs

Tags: matlab, ldpc

I am trying to implement the Belief Propagation (Sum-product algorithm) to decode LDPC codes in Matlab.
I have implemented the equations correctly and did a comparison between my implementation and the provided implementation in Matlab.
For some reason my implementation floors at BER = $10^{-2}$.
I suspect that this is due to the LLR values having a too large magnitude.
I tried to clip and even rescale the values, but this did not help.

Does somebody know how to solve the problem of numerical inaccuracies for the BP decoder in Matlab?

I understand that the provided decoder is far better since the developers spend many hours to optimize it.

--- EDIT ---
[image]

--- EDIT 2 ---
[image]

Comment: a BER of 1/100 sounds more like a bug than a potential for numerical optimization

Comment: Dear Marcus, thank you for your reply! Do you mean by bug that there is something wrong in my code? I published the code here [link](https://github.com/Cooltafel/LDPC_decoder). I have debugged this code several times to see if something goes wrong, but I think it is correct...

Comment: The thing about iterative decoders tends to be that they're quite good at repairing their own mistakes (source: I wrote horribly broken message passing algorithms myself); and Matlab's decoders can't work magic either, so if yours are significantly worse in a high BER regime like this, bugs are the nr1 assumptions. So that's where I'm coming from!

Comment: So, I'd recommend adding a plot to your question: Pick a **fixed** set of at least 1000 codewords (100 is not enough for statistic reliability of you have a BER in the range of 100, and such a short block code), e.g. by fixing the seed (`rng(seed)`) prior to generating your codewords. Then pick a fixed SNR (e.g. 5 dB), and plot the BER for both the matlab and your decoder over a growing number of maximum decoding iterations, from 2 to 32 iterations. (Assuming you can decode things at 10 iterations might be a bit optimistic. 30 is a good target, usually.)

Comment: At which point does your decoder exhibit a different "steepness" of the BER curve than the matlab decoder? If it's really numerical inaccuracy, that would come in relatively late. Unlikely to happen in the first 10 iterations! Please add that plot to your question.

Comment: Again thank you for your elaborate answer! I have added the plot. I see now that there is something wrong with my algorithm, the BER stays approximately constant. I think I have a mistake in the LLR calculation at the VNs.

Comment: lovely graph! Good work. Yeah! You can also plot a histogram of VN and CN weights over iteration number. In a correctly decoding decoder, these histograms should converge to "pretty sure", i.e. outwards.

Comment: I have found the error, I was incorrectly updating the LLRs at the VNs. Now it works as can be seen in the second figure. There is still some difference between the graphs in terms of BER. I am not sure where this comes from.

Comment: I haven't looked too closely at your code, but you do make sure to subtract the message you for from a node from the sum you're passing back to it, right?

Comment: Found and solved it! The implementations produce the same results, I was comparing two wrong BERs: the information bits with the codeword bits. Thank you for your help! The support really helped me to solve it :)